# Using Norms to Determine Factorisations in the Gaussian Integers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

In the set $\mathbb{Z}[i]:=\{a+bi:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ of Gaussian Integers, we define the *norm* to be $N:\mathbb{Z}[i]\to\mathbb{Z}$ by
$$
N(\alpha)=\alpha\alpha^*=a^2+b^2,\ \forall\alpha=a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i].
$$
We then use this to determine factorisations of Gaussian integers. Since if $\alpha\mid\beta$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $N(\alpha)\mid N(\beta)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Further, we know that if $\eta$ is a highest common factor of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and $h$ is a highest common factor of $N(\alpha)$ and $N(\beta)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, it follows that $N(\eta)\mid h$. My question is this:

When does $N(\eta)\neq h$? Is it possible to characterise such a case in terms of a prime factorisation?

I feel as though this is related to Fermat's theorem regarding the parity of the exponents of primes $q\equiv 3 \pmod 4$, i.e. an integer $n$ is a sum of squares (and therefore a norm of a Gaussian integer) iff in a prime factorisation
$$
n=2^{a_0}p_1^{a_1}\dotsm p_r^{a_r}q_1^{b_1}\dotsm q_s^{b_s} \qquad (*)$$
where $p_i\equiv 1\pmod 4,\  q_i\equiv 3\pmod 4$ are prime and $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{Z},\ \forall i$, has that all $b_i$ are even, but I've struggled to relate the two.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I've been trying to construct examples with some level of difficulty, and I'll share my attempts here.

First of all, we know that since $N(\eta)\mid h$ and $N(\eta)\neq h$, we must have that $h\neq 1$. Then $N(\alpha)$ and $N(\beta)$ must not be coprime. Further, for such Gaussian integers to exist, they must have the form of $(*)$. Then pick primes congruent to $1\bmod 4$, $\ p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ (or equivalently, take primes congruent to $3\bmod 4$, but square them) and let
$$
N(\alpha)=p_1p_2p_3, \quad N(\beta)=p_1p_2p_4.
$$
Then $h=p_1p_2$, and we may have $N(\eta)=p_1$ or $N(\eta)=p_2$, in particular, $N(\eta)\neq h$. Does this seem to be a reasonable method? Or is there some easier way.

Comment: How about we plug in some very specific numbers and see if we can make sense of this?

Let's say we're trying to figure out the factorization of $8 + 19i$. We have $N(8 + 19i) = 425$. And $425 = 5^2 \times 17$. Clearly 5 is a divisor of 85. So maybe $\alpha = 2 + i$ and $\beta = 2 + 9i$... oops, that doesn't work. Instead, let's do $$\frac{8 + 19i}{2 + i} = 7 + 6i = \beta.$$

Then $\gcd(\alpha, \beta) = \alpha$ and $\gcd(N(\alpha), N(\beta)) = N(\alpha)$. So not what you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm... let's try instead $24 + 57i$. Then $\alpha = 6 + 3i$ and $\beta = 7 + 6i$, $N(\alpha) = 45$, $N(\beta) = 85$, and $\gcd(N(\alpha), N(\beta)) = 5$.

This is a much more difficult question than I realized...

Comment: @RobertSoupe I've updated the main post with an attempt at building an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, let's plug in some specific numbers into the formula you built: $p_1 = 2 - i$, $p_2 = 2 + i$, $p_3 = 3 - 2i$, $p_4 = 3 + 2i$. Then $\alpha = 15 - 10i$, $N(\alpha) = 325$, $\beta = 15 + 10i$ and $N(\beta) = 325$ as well.

Clearly $\gcd(15 - 10i, 15 + 10i) = 5$, which has a norm of $25$, not $325$. It checks out, it might be the most elegant example possible.

This is what I was groping towards, so I'm glad I helped you get there.

Comment: Thank you, Robert, it's a bit of a relief to have an example. I'll update this page if I manage to fine tune the argument (for completeness).